# Relative performance of StatArbs strategy

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

This is a more general question regarding the performance of statistical arbitrage strategies... Are there any studies done on the performance of a large set of StatArb strategies? I want to have some type of benchmark for future evaluation of similar strategies, such that I can evaluate a StatArb strategy on a relative basis.

Comment: that's going to be difficult to find because everyone ( or most anyway ) has a strategy that's propietary so grouping strategies together can be problematic. essentially, no one provides enough specifics about their strategy so reading about performance based groupings doesn't really provide  much info anyway.

Comment: Adding to mark leeds' response, a lot of the stat-arb is derived from the trader having favourable order flow information and trading costs. If you're trading on latency and incomplete information, but were to find stat-arb, why would someone without those limitations not find it?

Comment: @markleeds I see what you are saying, thank you

Comment: your welcome. I'm sorry that I couldn't be more positive but atleast now you know to read any of those groupings reports  with skepticism.